# Python: Generate matrix of Nx4 integers who sum is a constant

Tags: python, matrix, integer

I have search the web which has provided various solution on how to produce a matrix of random numbers whose sum is a constant. My problem is slightly different. I want to generate an NX4 matrix of exhaustive list of integers such that sum of all numbers in the row is exactly 100. and integers have a range from [0,100]. I want to the integers to increment sequentially as opposed to random. How can I do it in Python?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`product` is a handy way of generating combinations

```
In [774]: from itertools import product

In [775]: [x for x in product(range(10),range(10)) if sum(x)==10]
Out[775]: [(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 1)]
```

The tuples sum to 10, and step sequentially (in the first value at least).

I can generalize it to 3 tuples, and it still runs pretty fast.

```
In [778]: len([x for x in product(range(100),range(100),range(100)) if sum(x)==100])
Out[778]: 5148
```

Length 4 tuples takes much longer (on an old machine),

```
In [780]: len([x for x in product(range(100),range(100),range(100),range(100)) if sum(x)==100])
Out[780]: 176847
```

So there's probably case to be made for solving this incrementally.

---

```
[x for x in product(range(100),range(100),range(100)) if sum(x)<=100]
```

runs much faster, producing the same number of of 3 tuples (within 1 or 2). And the 4th value can be derived that that `x`.

```
In [790]: timeit len([x+(100-sum(x),) for x in product(range(100),range(100),range(100)) if sum(x)<=100])
1 loops, best of 3: 444 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is simply brilliant and clean.

Comment: Can it be modified such that all numbers are a factors of 5? This is to reduce the matrix size. Thank you.

Comment: Use `range(0,100,5)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import random

def makerow(L, T, R):
    # make a row of size L and sum T, with the integers from 0-R, in ascending

    answer = []
    pool = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x<T, range(R+1)))
    for i in range(L-1):
        answer.append(random.choice(pool))
        T -= answer[-1]
        pool = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x<T, range(R+1)))
    answer.append(T)
    answer.sort()
    return answer

def makematrix(M, N, T, R):
    # make a matrix of M rows and N columns per row
    # each row adds up to T
    # using the numbers between 0-R

    return [makerow(N, T, R) for _ in range(M)]
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is not what I want. The solution looks great. I want the integers to increment or decrement sequentially to certain extent. In your e.g. the first number always seems to be <20 for makematrix(100,4,100,100).

Comment: @Zenvega: if you want your rows to be in sorted order, then statistically, it makes sense that the first number is in [0, R/L]

Comment: actually, when I mentioned that I want the integers to increment sequentially, I didn't mean sorted in each row, I meant the first number in each row increment in value, then the second number in each row, then the third number and the fourth. Basically, they are weights and they shouldn't be sorted. each column should be given equal opportunity to have any number.